# I'm using a sequence in Factory Girl to get unique values but I'm getting validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a model defined this way

```
class Lga < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :code
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

I've defined a factory for Lgas with

```
Factory.sequence(:lga_id) { |n| n + 10000 }

Factory.define :lga do |l|
  id = Factory.next :lga_id
  l.code "lga_#{id}"
  l.name "LGA #{id}"
end
```

However, when I run

```
Factory.create(:lga)
Factory.create(:lga)
```

in `script/console` I get

```
>> Factory.create(:lga)
=> #<Lga id: 2, code: "lga_10001", name: "LGA 10001", created_at: "2010-03-18  23:55:29", updated_at: "2010-03-18 23:55:29">
>> Factory.create(:lga)
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Code has already been taken
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that `code` and `name` attributes were not so called *lazy attributes*. I had thought of writing something like:

```
Factory.define :lga do |l|
  l.code { |n| "lga_#{n+10000}" }
end
```

but I wanted to reuse the id in the `name` attribute too. You can make sure
than `id` is evaluated each time `Factory.create` is called by putting it in an `after_build` hook.

```
Factory.define :lga do |l|
   l.after_build do |lga|
     id = Factory.next :lga_id
     lga.code = "lga_#{id}"
     lga.name = "LGA #{id}"
   end
end
```

This only works in FactoryGirl 1.2.3 and above.

Comment: I think you've left a debugger line in your last example code block ;)

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is still correct but in newer versions of FactoryGirl you will get a warning.

```
Factory.next has been depreciated. Use FactoryGirl.generate instead.
```

New Code should look like this:

```
Factory.define :lga do |l|
   l.after_build do |lga|
     id = FactoryGirl.generate :lga_id
     lga.code = "lga_#{id}"
     lga.name = "LGA #{id}"
   end
end
```

Source: http://notesofgreg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/foolproof-factorygirl-sequence.html